# Learning using layers and CoreAnimation for iphone

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Except for the official docs, what is a good resource for learning how to use CALayers and Core Animation correclty?

Answer (score 0):

See this book: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone